# how to keep wizard open after printing xls report in odoo

Tags: python, odoo, xlsx, odoo-10

In odoo 10 community below method is executed for printing xls report.but the wizard is closed after printing the report.I want the wizard to be remain opened after report is printed. 
Please suggest how to achieve this.

```
 def export_xls(self):
            context = self._context
            datas = {'ids': context.get('active_ids', [])}
            datas['model'] = 'product.product'
            datas['form'] = self.read()[0]
            for field in datas['form'].keys():
                if isinstance(datas['form'][field], tuple):
                    datas['form'][field] = datas['form'][field][0]
            if context.get('xls_export'):
                return {'type': 'ir.actions.report.xml',
                        'report_name': 'export_stockinfo_xls.stock_report_xls.xlsx',
                        'datas': datas,
                        'name': 'Current Stock'
                        }
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this:-

```
<report
 id="project_xlsx"
 model="project.project"
 string="Project Excel Report"
 report_type="xlsx"
 name="yourmodule_name.project_xlsx"
 file="yourmodule_name.project_xlsx"
 attachment_use="True"
 menu = "False"
/>
```

Make python call:-

```
return self.env.ref('yourmodule_name.project_xlsx').report_action(self, data=datas)
```

It'll not close the wizard that you have opened.